# Using 5V output from an Adafruit SHT40 humidity sensor with DAQ system

Tags: arduino, sensor, humidity, daq

Using the setup guide for the SHT40, the only way I can get humidity and temperature from the SHT40 sensor is to hook it up to an Arduino and interpret the data coming from the SDL and SCA pins with code. If I want to make it work with my MCC DAQ box (which is reading thermocouple data) and have all my sensors sending data to the same place, do I need to use a 5V signal to the DAQ? If so, how do I convert the voltage to a humidity reading? Is there a way to have the Arduino communicate with the DAQ? I understand this could be a broad question, but a starting point would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note, the [SHT40](https://sensirion.com/products/catalog/SHT40/) is a Sensirion brand.  [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4885) made the break-out board for it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use a digital protocol like Serial or I2C for the Arduino to communicate with the DAQ box. Check your specific DAQ model’s datasheet to see if it supports any of these.

If it supports I2C, you might also be able to hook SHT40 directly to it. A thermocouple just creates an analog voltage so the DAQ cannot read data from the Arduino (which does not have a true digital to analog converter) in the same way.